# reversing list items gives wrong position in getview()

Tags: listview, arraylist, reverse

I am very new in Android.I am stuck to a problem that I have a adapter.and i have to populate my list in reverse orderbut when the position is not reversed as listItems.
here is my code

```
public PageListAdapter(Context context) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    // FilesInFolder = GetFiles("/sdcard/Download");

    filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/openedpages/";
    file = new File(filePath);
    if (file.exists()) {

        filenew = file.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < file.listFiles().length; i++) {

            arr.add(filenew[i].getName());

        }

    }
    Collections.reverse(arr);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowview = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.listelement, parent, false);
        pagename = (TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.listitem);
        //
        pagename.setText(arr.get(position));
        arrnum.add(position);
        return rowview;
    } else
        return convertView;

}
```

here i reversed my arraylist..but the position of listitems are coming as opposite order.new added item is not getting the position 0.
Please help me out.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*First*, you don't need your extra list `arrpostion`. Your `arr` already keeps items in reversed order.

Just set your text with : `pagename.setText(arr.get(position))`;

*Second*, you have to populate your recycled `convertView` with correct data (similarly to what you do it when creating a new one), while you currently return :

```
} else
        return convertView;
```

After fixing that you will have your listview showing what you want.

Comment: I did that only.. but still it on click it is giving me wrong position.

Comment: First, are the items shown in expected order on screen ? what onClick are you talking about ?

Comment: i have a drawerlist where i am setting this adapter.so when i click on drawerlist.onclicklistener then it is not giving me as reversed order.list items are reversed but the positions are same as before

Comment: private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
   ListView.OnItemClickListener {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position,
    long id) {

   isListSelected = true;
   System.out.println("selected index: " + position);

   selectItem(position);
  }

 }

Comment: But you do have your items _shown_ in correct (reversed) order in your drawerlist ?